# Template default argument missing with basic_istream class

Tags: c++, istream

I was checking the implementation of the basic_istream class. I found the implementation at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00113_source.html#l00095.
Let me add a snippet.

[image]

I have to pass two template arguments when creating an object of the basic_istream class since the default argument is not declared in the basic_istream class declaration.

I can still build an object with just one template argument, as shown in the example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    basic_stringbuf<char>string("Basic ios",ios_base::in| ios_base::out);
    basic_istream<char> bis(&string);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody clarify how it works for me?

Comment: **Hint**: Even if you don't pass any template argument explicitly it will work. For eg, `basic_istream bis(&string)` will work.

Comment: In case you didn't get from the hint, the template arguments can be deduced from the passed constructor argument's args.

Comment: Here i want to understand how default template argument concept works without defining the default template argument.

Comment: *"I have to pass two template arguments when creating an object of the basic_istream..."* **No that is a wrong assumption/understanding.** As `basic_istream bis(&string);` will also work.

Comment: Also naming a variable `string` when you have `using namespace std;` is not a good idea.

Comment: *"i want to understand how default template argument concept works..."* Looking at implementation is not a good way to learn c++. Instead use a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains these basic things. **I see a lot of bad programming habits in the code.**

Comment: *" the default argument is not declared in the basic_istream class declaration."* But it is - in the header [`<iosfwd>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd#Synopsis). You are looking at the class *definition*, not its *declaration*.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;** [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) from c++17 can be used to deduce the two template parameters.

---

> I  have to pass two template arguments when creating an object of the basic_istream class since the default argument is not declared in the basic_istream class declaration.

No, that is a wrong assumption. [`std::baisc_stream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream) has a constructor that can deduce the template arguments from the passed constructor argument. The constructor is:

```
explicit basic_istream( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb );   (1)
```

This constructor will be used in your example, to deduce the two template parameters. See [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

This is the reason why your code will compile in c++17 but not in c++14 or earlier. In particular, because CTAD is available from C++17 onwards.